# Question regarding general equation of second degree

Tags: algebra-precalculus, analytic-geometry

I know this ---  $13x^2 +10xy+13y^2 -42x + 6y -27 =0$ is an ellipse as $h^2=25 < ab=169$  and the discriminant is non-zero.

Am I right ? What more can I say about this curve?  Can I get the equation of the ellipse in the usual form if it is an ellipse?

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: It is a real ellipse, but note that it is not true that if $h^2\lt ab$ and $\Delta\not=0$, then it is a real ellipse. For example, the imaginary ellipse $4x^2+y^2+4=0$ satisfies $h^2\lt ab$ and $\Delta\not=0$. You might want to see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuadraticCurve.html).

Comment: Is there any easy way to show that this is a real ellipse with the lengths of the Major and Minor axes ? @Mathlove

Comment: If you know linear algebra, you can write the ellipse as a quadratic form, where the axes of the ellipse correspond to the eigenvectors of the matrix. Unfortunately I don't know exactly how to do this, so you will need to wait for an answer.

Comment: I have a short explanation using an example ellipse.  See: https://qpsllc.com/Ch_1/1.12%20Ellipse/1.12.5%20Standard%20Ellipse%20Equation.html#GeneralConicForm  Also, there is a great deal of information about this on Wikipedia.